# How to scan all bar codes of type AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturedevice

My scanner can scan this barcode. [image]

But not this barcode.

[image]

This is the code i'm using.

```
#pragma mark - IBAction method implementation

- (void)startStopReading {
    if (!_isReading) {
        // This is the case where the app should read a QR code when the start button is tapped.
        if ([self startReading]) {
            // If the startReading methods returns YES and the capture session is successfully
            // running, then change the start button title and the status message.
            [_decodedLabel setText:@"Scanning for QR Code..."];
        }
    }
    else{
        // In this case the app is currently reading a QR code and it should stop doing so.
        [self stopReading];
        // The bar button item's title should change again.
    }

    // Set to the flag the exact opposite value of the one that currently has.
    _isReading = !_isReading;
}


#pragma mark - Private method implementation

- (BOOL)startReading {
    NSError *error;

    // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video
    // as the media type parameter.
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];

    if (!input) {
        // If any error occurs, simply log the description of it and don't continue any more.
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }

    // Initialize the captureSession object.
    _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    // Set the input device on the capture session.
    [_captureSession addInput:input];


    // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
    AVCaptureMetadataOutput *captureMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [_captureSession addOutput:captureMetadataOutput];

    // Create a new serial dispatch queue.
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue;
    dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
    [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code]];

    // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
    _videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
    [_videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    [_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:_viewPreview.layer.bounds];
    [_viewPreview.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];

    // Start video capture.
    [_captureSession startRunning];

    return YES;
}


-(void)stopReading{
    // Stop video capture and make the capture session object nil.
    [_captureSession stopRunning];
    _captureSession = nil;

    // Remove the video preview layer from the viewPreview view's layer.
    [_videoPreviewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
}

#pragma mark - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate method implementation

-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputMetadataObjects:(NSArray *)metadataObjects fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection{

    // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
    if (metadataObjects != nil && [metadataObjects count] > 0) {
        // Get the metadata object.
        AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject *metadataObj = [metadataObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([[metadataObj type] isEqualToString:AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code]) {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text,
            // stop reading and change the bar button item's title and the flag's value.
            // Everything is done on the main thread.
            [_decodedLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[metadataObj stringValue] waitUntilDone:NO];

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopReading) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            _isReading = NO;
            [self barCodeReadGoToNextPage:[metadataObj stringValue]];

            // If the audio player is not nil, then play the sound effect.
            if (_audioPlayer) {
                [_audioPlayer play];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work for all barcodes of type AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code

Comment: That second barcode is a Code 128 barcode, not an EAN13 barcode.

Comment: As far as I'm aware I used the same barcode the one is just square. Even if I accidentally used different bar codes both are  EAN13 because the camera was able to scan the above barcode when it was a square

Comment: Also I tried 128 and it didn't scan at all because its EAN13 barcode

Comment: Sorry you were right.

Comment: May I suggest either removing this question if no longer relevant or updating it as needed based on this info.